# How can I use saved passwords with selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to make a tool that does things on your website account. Some things use reCAPTCHA after you log in, so I want to know how I could automatically log in with firefox's saved passwords on selenium. So far I tried viewing Firefox's saved passwords with a text editor, but that failed.

Comment: How would a saved password get around reCAPTCHA? Usually if you have logged in, filled out the reCAPTCHA and you do not get prompted for this the text time, it is because the server set a cookie on the browser. Saved passwords don't affect this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @GregBurghardt So the saved passwords don't matter, it is the cookies that would do this?

Comment: Saved passwords won't affect reCAPTCHA in any way I can think of. Sites will require you to fill out reCAPTCHA the first time you visit, and then set a cookie after filling it out properly, so they don't bother users who have already proven themselves to be human (or as much proof as we can currently provide).